# nginx Cross-Origin Resource issues

Tags: nginx, cors

I've read almost every post on stackoverflow in regards to CORS and whatever I try does not work. Here is my setup:

```
Ubuntu (digital ocean)  
nginx 
cdn: cdn77.com (not amazon) 
cloudflare
wordpress with wp fastest cache
```

Each time a new setting was done I've purged cloudflare and restarted nginx.

This is what I've tried:

.htaccess (doesn't work)

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css|css)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Cache-Control, Pragma, Origin, Authorization, Content-Type, X-Requested-With"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, PUT, POST"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

nginx (doesn't work)

```
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With";
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, HEAD, OPTIONS";
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
```

I am pulling my hair out trying to figure out why font awesome wont show its icons on my site which is on a different domain.

Comment: Does it have the correct mime type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.htaccess` files are apache only, it will never work for Nginx.

With nginx it should work if theses headers are added to the font HTTP response... but it seems you do not own the fonts and you take the fonts from another website. The **CORS headers need to be set by this website**, not yours. Check what are theses headers on the fonts, and check that your website is allowed to use the fonts from there (else you will have to download the fonts on your website and add the headers on an nginx location based on the font extension.

I guess you confuse [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) headers and **[CSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Security_Policy) headers** (**C**ontent **S**ecurity **P**olicy). Where you can give a list of allowed resources for your website.